# Wifi suddenly stopped working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

I'm using a Ubuntu Budgie 18.04. I've been using it for a year without any problems, but suddenly the wifi stopped working, and in the network settings, I get the message "No Wifi Adapter Found".

The result of the `iwconfig` command is

```
enp59s0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

and the result of the `lspci` command tells me that I have a **network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560[Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)**.

I tried some solutions I found but it doesn't work. Please, help me!

Comment: Please add output of the command `sudo lshw -class network` to your question.